# Approaches we can follow to allow our customers to interact with our own APIs using Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, office-integration

I have more than 6 years of experience in Power Apps & SharePoint. but i am working on a new project which created a challenge for me, to understand from where i should start and which approach to take. The general requirements are:-

1. The customer has their own ERP system where almost all the functionalities are exposed as REST APIs.
2. The customer has a centralized ERP system, for their 50++ clients
3. The customer wants to allow clients to interact with their system (through the APIs), where the customer can build their own Power Apps. So for example they can create a Power App forms to create a new Payable Account, where they can hide certain fields based on some drop-down selection, and send the result to create the item on our system.

so based on my experience, we can enable this type of integration using 2 approaches:-

1. First approach, is to build our own connector & actions>> so users can add the connector to any Power App, and start their work..
2. Second approach, is to build some documentations on how the users can call the raw ERP API's through Power Apps, and even we can build sample Power Apps for the clients to download and customize.

so i am not sure which approach best fit our needs? and why? also is there 3 rd approach i am unaware of that we can use.

Hint, we can have a fast approach to deliver something in 4-5 weeks, and then we can have a long term approach in 5-6 months..so things can be flexible.

Any advice will be highly appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: We would need more information about the client needs to understand the best approach e.g. how much technical work they want to complete themselves? how much customisation they would like to do?

Comment: @CallumCrowley since i posed the question, i have more info .. now we will need to create a custom connector for one Post request, and we will  use the OAuth 2.0 as the security option inside the custom connector.. thanks

Comment: The community will not know the answer to your question, as it is dependent on how those clients feel about the technical challenges of each option e.g. they may feel option 1 is too much work for them while the community might not. Both options may be suitable but only one is acceptable to the clients.